# Drawing a spiral with two different methods

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I tried to draw a spiral $y=(a+bi)^x$ in a complex plane, but I found the differences. The method I used was:

\begin{align}
& a+bi = (a, b). \\
& r_0=r_{a, b}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \theta_0=\theta_{a, b}=\arctan\left(\frac b a\right). \\
& \text{Note. } r_{(a, b) \cdot (c, d)}=r_{a, b} \cdot r_{c, d}, \theta_{(a, b) \cdot (c, d)} = \theta_{a, b} + \theta_{c, d}. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \text{let } (a+bi)^x = (a_x, b_x), r_{a_x, b_x} = (r_{a, b})^x, \theta_{a_x, b_x} = x \cdot \theta_{a, b}. \\
\ \\
& r = (r_0)^{\frac {\theta}{\theta_0}} \tag{1}\label{(1)} \\
& y=x\cdot \tan \left( \left( \log_{a^2+b^2} (x^2+y^2) \right) \cdot \arctan \left( \frac b a \right) \right) \tag{2}\label{(2)} \\
\end{align}

By drawing these two graphs, the plane has two DIFFERENT charts:

[image]

Is it because of the degree and the radian? Can anyone explain this...